# jpa OneToMany / ManyToOne how to save data

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm learnig jpa and have a general question to saving data.

Suppose we have two entities:

Parent entity: Person

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>();
```

Child entity: Car

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "customer_car", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
private Person person;
```

The question is: What is the correct way to save data:

1. Person-Controller: I should use a @PostMapping to post a person with many cars.
2. Car-Controller: I should use a @PostMapping to post a car with many persons.
3. Option 1 and option 2 are possible

Comment: There is no one correct way - everything depends on the application's use cases and requirements. If you want to have endpoints that can handle an entire object graph, do so. If you want to have multiple endpoints and require multiple calls on each resource to setup such a graph, that works too. Generally, I setup my resources with a parent->Child hierarchy so that I can persist a parent and all its children, but the child resource does not affect (or change) anything on the parent - this is to reduce the risk of stale overwrites of leaf nodes affecting large graphs inadvertently.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much :)